# How do I display the record count of a related model with CakePHP?

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, count

I have two models. Lets say they are "Posts" and "Comments". In an admin view for Posts, I want to display how many comments are on that post. I am confused on where to put the code. In the controller or the view? I would like it to be in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to [cache your count](http://book.cakephp.org/view/816/counterCache-Cache-your-count). With this approach, you'd add the field `comment_count` to your `posts` table, then modify your `Comment` model's `belongsTo` association like this:

```
class Comment extends AppModel
{
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Post' => array( 'counterCache' => true )
    );
}
```

Anytime a new `Comment` record is created, the `comment_count` of the associated `Post` record is incremented, and decremented anytime an associated `Comment` is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you're right.You should get data in the controller,then display it in the view.And what you describe in your question is exactly like the [example in the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/82/hasMany).Assume you have related then with `Post hasMany Comment`,you can find the count using:

```
$comment_count = $this->Post->Comment->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('Comment.post_id'=>$postid)));
```